# How to campare two tables in one schema using not equal value <>

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query to compare two tables but it returns me error:

- subquery returns more than 1 row

  ```
     Select id, 
            lname 
     from db.details 
     where id = 'sample' 
     and lname <> (Select lname from db.initialdetail);
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NOT IN` as subquery is giving a set

```
Select id, 
       lname 
from db.details 
where id = 'sample' 
and lname NOT IN (Select lname from db.initialdetail);
```